# Log-scale informs on relative changes (multiplicative). What does exponential scale inform on?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Log-scale informs on relative changes (multiplicative), while linear-scale informs on absolute changes (additive). When do you use each? When you care about relative changes, use the log-scale; when you care about absolute changes, use linear-scale. This is true for distributions, but also for any quantity or changes in quantities.

Say you have a function $xy=1$ with doubly linear scale. You convert the scale to a doubly exponential scale. What I mean by a "doubly exponential scale" is that it is the inverse of the log-log scale.

> What does a doubly exponential scale inform on?
>
> In general when you convert the scale to exponential what is preserved with regards to the function after the conversion?

Comment: Can you explain what is a "doubly exponential scale"? Is it the scale used in a log-log plot?

Comment: It's the opposite of the scale used in a log-log plot @Rahul

Comment: In other words, if you take the curve $xy=1$ and convert it to exp-exp scale, and then convert back to log-log scale you recover the original function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log and log-log graphs is used to fit rapidly increasing data onto a page.  Exp and exp-exp graphs would be used to fit rapidly decreasing data onto a page without cramming all the small stuff so close together that the data blurs.